# python numpy ValueError:shapes (171,) and (784,500) not aligned: 171

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have data vector (1 coloumn) and I'm using

```
def propup(self, vis):
   pre_sigmoid_activation = numpy.dot(vis, self.W) + self.hbias
   return sigmoid(pre_sigmoid_activation)
```

but i getting error

> ValueError: shapes (171,) and (784,500) not aligned: 171 (dim 0) !=
>   784 (dim 0)

Comment: You are violating rules of matrix vector multiplication.

Comment: Try to reshape your vector [Numpy-Reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Comment: But how is an array of 171 elements supposed to interact with a 2d array 784 by 500?  They don't have any dimensions in common.  Matrix multiplication doesn't make sense with those shapes, nor does broadcasted elementwise multiplication.

Comment: I have been try reshape my vectors but i get ValueError: shapes (0,) and (784,500) not aligned: 0 (dim 0) != 784 (dim 0) @GarbageCollector

Comment: I'm also still confused, I've converted into matrix form using reshape. but this does not help @hpaulj

Answer (score 0):

A dot product between a matrix and a vector is defined as [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ii8K.jpg).

This implies that the width of the matrix and the height of the vector should be identical.

In your case `ves.shape = [,171]` which is the height of the vector but `self.W.shape = [784, 500]` meaning the width of the matrix `self.W` is 784.
In order for `numpy.dot` to work properly you need to make sure `ves.shape = [x, 784]` where x is some integer.

Without more code i could only guess that you are trying to train a Neural Net to solve the MNIST problem (the 784 dimension is pretty specific).
So make sure that you are sending the right vector to `propup()`.
In any case here are a few great sources on matrix multiplication:
Matrix multiplication: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html